# Windows 7 cannot burn a DVD-R at 4x or 8x? (it seems to have to use the MAX speed)

Tags: windows-7, dvd, speed, burning

Windows 7 is great to have the ability to burn an .iso into a DVD-R, but it seems like there is no way to change the speed to 8x or 4x?  (so it may go "max", which is 16x)

because some of my DVD drives cannot read data all the time if the disc was burned at 16x, that's why usually i limit it to 8x.  also, some articles say that disc burned at 4x can last a longer time, so i am tempted to burn something at 4x sometimes.

any method or hack that can make it happen?

Comment: i am 100% sure, my computer let me select the burning speed when using the built-in recorder. but i never used the builtin iso burning tool, maybe is different?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows only has some basic burning features, nothing fancy.

If you want more, you may use **[InfraRecorder](http://infrarecorder.org/)** instead and adjust the write speed to your liking.

[image]

*InfraRecorder is open source, free and portable (no installation required).*

Comment: i see.  how is it compared to ImgBurn? http://www.imgburn.com/

Comment: Another one worth looking into is CD Burner XP (free).  Never tried InfraRecorder, I'll have to give it a try.